# ModernCV banking style default space between address and phone

Tags: moderncv

Moderncv has a line of empty space between address and phone/email, like this: [image: figure]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{banking}
\name{Sherlock}{Holmes}
\address{221B Baker Street}{London}{U.K.} % Your current address
\phone[mobile] {+44~(0)71234 00000}    % Your mobile phone number
\email{superdetective@mail.com} 
\begin{document}
\makecvtitle
\end{document}
```

How do I remove/decrease that space by shifting the phone and email line up?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For the current version of `moderncv` you can use the following "hack".  But please keep an eye on the version number `moderncv.cls 2015/07/28 v2.0.0 modern curriculum vitae and letter document class`.  If the version changes it could be that this code can't work longer ...

In line 21 of the following MWE (marked with `<===============`) you see the code:

```
\flushmakeheaddetails\@firstmakeheaddetailselementtrue\par\vspace{-\baselineskip}\null}
```

In the original file `moderncvheadiii.sty` in line 91 you will find:

```
\flushmakeheaddetails\@firstmakeheaddetailselementtrue\\\null}
```

The changing of `\\` to `\par\vspace{-\baselineskip}` gives the result you want.

BTW: I would not do this, the cv looks better with the space, I think.

Complete code:

```
% http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/277361/moderncv-banking-style-default-space-between-address-and-phone
\listfiles
\documentclass[12pt]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{banking}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\makehead}{%\@initializecommand
  \setlength{\makeheaddetailswidth}{0.8\textwidth}%
  \hfil%
  \parbox{\makeheaddetailswidth}{%
    \centering%
    % name and title
    \namestyle{\@firstname~\@lastname}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\@title}{}}{}{\titlestyle{~|~\@title}}\\% \isundefined doesn't work on \@title, as LaTeX itself defines \@title (before it possibly gets redefined by \title) 
    % optional detailed information
    \if@details{%
      \addressfont\color{color2}%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@addressstreet}}{}{\addtomakeheaddetails{\addresssymbol\@addressstreet}%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscity}{}}{}{\addtomakeheaddetails[~--~]{\@addresscity}}% if \addresstreet is defined, \addresscity and \addresscountry will always be defined but could be empty
        \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscountry}{}}{}{\addtomakeheaddetails[~--~]{\@addresscountry}}%
        \flushmakeheaddetails\@firstmakeheaddetailselementtrue\par\vspace{-\baselineskip}\null}% <========================
      \collectionloop{phones}{% the key holds the phone type (=symbol command prefix), the item holds the number
        \addtomakeheaddetails{\csname\collectionloopkey phonesymbol\endcsname\collectionloopitem}}%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@email}}{}{\addtomakeheaddetails{\emailsymbol\emaillink{\@email}}}%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@homepage}}{}{\addtomakeheaddetails{\homepagesymbol\httplink{\@homepage}}}%
      \collectionloop{socials}{% the key holds the social type (=symbol command prefix), the item holds the link
        \addtomakeheaddetails{\csname\collectionloopkey socialsymbol\endcsname\collectionloopitem}}%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@extrainfo}}{}{\addtomakeheaddetails{\@extrainfo}}%
    \flushmakeheaddetails}\fi}\\[2.5em]}
\makeatother


\name{Sherlock}{Holmes}
\address{221B Baker Street}{London}{U.K.} % Your current address
\phone[mobile] {+44~(0)71234 00000}    % Your mobile phone number
\email{superdetective@mail.com} 
\begin{document}
\makecvtitle
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image: changed header without blank line]

A second way is to use command `patchcmd` of package `etoolbox` to change the line showed above.

The code for `\patchcmd` is (`\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` are needed because `@` is used in the searched line):

```
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\makehead}{%search
  \flushmakeheaddetails\@firstmakeheaddetailselementtrue\\\null}{%replace
  \flushmakeheaddetails\@firstmakeheaddetailselementtrue\par\vspace{-\baselineskip}\null}{%success
  }{%failure
  }
\makeatother
```

Then you have the complete MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{banking}
%\usepackage{etoolbox} % already loaded by moderncv!

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\makehead}{%search
  \flushmakeheaddetails\@firstmakeheaddetailselementtrue\\\null}{%replace
  \flushmakeheaddetails\@firstmakeheaddetailselementtrue\par\vspace{-\baselineskip}\null}{%success
  }{%failure
  }
\makeatother


\name{Sherlock}{Holmes}
\address{221B Baker Street}{London}{U.K.} % Your current address
\phone[mobile] {+44~(0)71234 00000}    % Your mobile phone number
\email{superdetective@mail.com} 
\begin{document}
\makecvtitle
\end{document}
```

with the same result. Thanks to @Werner for his comment.

Comment: It seems more convenient to do `\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\makehead}{\\\null}{\par\vspace{-\baselineskip}\null}{}{}` (I've added the `\vspace`.