# A too big line jump in moderncv class

Tags: moderncv, line-spacing

Here my MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}

\moderncvstyle{banking}
\moderncvcolor{blue}
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}

\name{A}{B}
\title{B A}
\address{4}{7}{C}
\phone[mobile]{06~01~02~03~04}
\email{@}

\begin{document}
\makecvtitle
\end{document}
```

And the result it gives me:

[image: Compilation of MWE]

I have highlighted my problem in red dots. I don't get why there's a line jump here. I had this example compiled a while ago and this line jump wasn't there … I'm compiling this using `xelatex` on a ArchLinux system. My TeX Live versions are

```
local/texlive-latexextra 2015.38831-1 (texlive-most)
    TeX Live - Large collection of add-on packages for LaTeX
```

Which corresponds to `moderncv.cls` version

```
\ProvidesClass{moderncv}[2015/07/28 v2.0.0 modern curriculum vitae and letter document class]
```

This question is a duplicate of [ModernCV banking style default space between address and phone](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/277361/moderncv-banking-style-default-space-between-address-and-phone)
which already has an ad-hoc answer depending on the `moderncv.cls` version.

Is there any other (nicer) way to fix this?

Comment: Firstly, it depends on whether the author decides to change something in the next version. It also seems hacky to latex users which are not tex savyy

Comment: Well, at last the problem is that the class `moderncv` is not build using variables for several parts of the layout. It uses "hard coded" layouts.  And that is the reason that one has to patch the class, with the disadvantage if the class code is changed it could be the patch has to be reworked.  That is the only way to get the result you want ...  The only other alternative is to write an own class, but that needs a lot of TeX knowledge ...