# Reduce space between address and phone/e-mail in moderncv

Tags: spacing, moderncv

Fairly new to latex and I want to decrease the space between the address line and the line with e-mail/phone on it in moderncv.

[image: Picture Here]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{banking}                            
\moderncvcolor{blue}                                
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}
\usepackage{import}

\name{My}{Name}
\address{Blah Blah address, Blahh }{}{}
\phone[mobile]{+44 12345 12345}                   
\email{myname@gmail.com}                              
\homepage{website.com}
```

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/96730/90297

Comment: I actually saw those answers before but when i try and use \vspace*{-5mm} it just gives a space between the entire header and the first section. I specifically want the space between the address and phone lines

Comment: How about the answer to [ModernCV banking style default space between address and phone](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/277361/moderncv-banking-style-default-space-between-address-and-phone)

Comment: Thank you that's what I needed! Messed around with that and got what I needed.

Comment: Excellent, as the question I linked to covers the same problem and has the answer you require I've flagged this question as a duplicate of that one.